# Execute SQL Server stored procedure through VBA which does not return rows

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

How to execute special SQL Server stored procedure through Excel VBA? Special because it does not return rows like this procedure:

```sql
select * from tab1
```

How to execute the procedure which let's say prepares reports, like this one:

```sql
select * 
into tab2
from tab1
```

which does not return any rows.

I am using this VBA code:

```vb
Dim cnn As Object
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim ConnectionString As String
cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=MYSERVERNAME;Database=MYDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
cnn.Open

Sql = "EXEC [dbo].[Procedure_make_report] 'param1'"
Set rs = cnn.Execute(Sql)
```

I get the error:

> Runtime error 2147217900

I found a clue here:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541498-RESOLVED-runtime-error-2147217900-(80040e14)-incorrect-syntax-error

but I do not know what **action query** is.

Comment: You can use `cnn.Execute` to run a SQL command or a stored procedure. It's not really clear where your error happens currently.

Comment: Update. I added the last line to code which causes error. `Set rs = cnn.Execute(Sql)` Can you write full line of VBA code please.

Comment: You don't need a recordset so: `cnn.Execute Sql`

Comment: @Rory That did it! Thank you! Answer accepted.

Comment: Also as an extra - add `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your stored procedure. Excel can often throw an error if this is not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments of Rory and Tom, I leave the answer which works.

```
Dim cnn As Object
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandType = 1      ' adCmdText
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120 ' number of seconds to time out

Dim ConnectionString As String
cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=MYSERVERNAME;Database=MYDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
cnn.Open

Dim SQL As String
SQL = "EXEC [dbo].[Procedure_make_report] 'param1'"

cnn.Open
    cmd.CommandText = SQL
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cmd.Execute

If Not cnn Is Nothing Then
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
End If
```