# VBA to open and run .sql file and copy the result in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am a bit new to this so my apologies in advance for any mistakes. I am trying to open and execute a sql query which is saved in C drive. The sql works fine. I did not write that sql and it is a very big file so would not like to add the code in VBA. I have been searching on this site and other places but struggling to make this work. I have had some or the other problem each time. I am pasting the code below for you to have a look and help me please. I have created this function which I am using in my VBA code.

```
Public Function ss()


'Open Connection
Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection
Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection

'Set Connection String
Dim sCon As String
sCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True;User 
ID='*****';Password='*****';Initial Catalog=****;Data Source=*******;Use 
Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption 
for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"

oCon.Open sCon 'Connect established

'Create recordset
Dim ps As ADODB.Recordset
Set ps = New ADODB.Recordset

'Set & execute SQL Command
Dim pCMD As ADODB.Command
Set pCMD = New ADODB.Command
Set pCMD.ActiveConnection = oCon

Dim filename As String
filename = "C:\Users\???????????\******.sql"


'select data
pCMD.CommandText = 
CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(filename).ReadAll()
Set ps = pCMD.Execute(, , adCmdText)

Debug.Print ps.GetRows

If ps.EOF = False Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset ps

'Close connection
Set ps = Nothing
Set pCMD = Nothing
oCon.Close
Set oCon = Nothing

End Function
```

Debug.Print has only been used to see the result but it is showing the same error "Run-time error '3704'  Operations is not allowed when the object is closed. After trying so many different things I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong.

Can someone please help?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest solution for you is to modify the end of the stored procedure so when executed, it insert all the results in a table. The next time you execute the SP you just have to `TRUCATE` the table and `INSERT` new results.

**Execute the SP**

You can call the SP from Excel with VBA using some code you can find here on StackOverflow, for example the following (which I've taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789813/1008588) answer):

```
Dim cnn As Object
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandType = 1      ' adCmdText
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120 ' number of seconds to time out

Dim ConnectionString As String
cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=MYSERVERNAME;Database=MYDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
cnn.Open

Dim SQL As String
SQL = "EXEC [dbo].[Procedure_make_report] 'param1'"

cnn.Open
    cmd.CommandText = SQL
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cmd.Execute

If Not cnn Is Nothing Then
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing
End If
```

**Retrive results into Excel**

Now that the results of the SP are stored into a table of you DB you can import them into Excel with ODBC connection as shown [here](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/04/29/load-power-query-directly-to-power-pivot-in-excel-2010/) or with [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4585/using-microsoft-query-in-excel-to-retreive-sql-server-data/) procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I will give this a try though I would really like to find out if there is a way to do this directly opening and running the sql file and then copying all records to my excel file.